# fopen() path for private and public keys

Tags: php, fopen

My question is in relation to finding my public and private key sets within my file structure. I am quite incompetent with this concept, so please bear with me.

Currently, to open my private and public key pairs, I use the following expression:

```
fopen(dirname(__FILE__) . '/rsa_private_key.pem', 'r');
```

`dirname(__FILE__)` directs to `/vagrant/opencart/upload/catalog/controller/payment`, which is where this script that gets executed also resides. So, the private/public key pair resides in the same folder as the script that opens it.

I am doing some file restructuring, and have created a new folder under the path : `/vagrant/opencart/upload/keys`, where both my private and public keys now reside.

However, I am not quite sure how to point my `fopen()` to it. Since I am currently developing on my local machine, I could, say, for now use an absolute path, but soon this will be on different servers, so I cannot use absolute path forever.

My question is, how do I point `fopen()` to this path: `/vagrant/opencart/upload/keys`?

Comment: `fopen(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../keys', 'r')` or the full path `fopen('/vagrant/opencart/upload/keys', 'r')` .. `but soon this will be on different servers, so I cannot use absolute path forever.` you can define a variable in config or found in script once which will have path to the root of the script and related all other paths to it.

Comment: @Cheery The `../../` would move our directory up two parents, right?

Comment: `define('KEY_PATH', '....'); fopen(KEY_PATH . 'file.pem');`

Comment: @theGreenCabbage yes and instead of `dirname(__FILE__)` you can use `__DIR__`

Comment: Thanks, you all provided solutions - but which one is the most desirable one? Would this work across all systems, since while I am developing on a Mac, the server this code will finally reside in is a Debian server. Would this affect the relativity of the paths?

Comment: @theGreenCabbage no, this relative path works everywhere. But I suggest to find the path to the script once during its initialization and get other paths with respect to it.

Comment: @Cheery Hmm. I am getting this error: `Warning: fopen(/vagrant/opencart/upload/catalog/controller/payment../../keys/rsa_private_key.pem): failed to open stream:` I am currently using: `fopen(dirname(__FILE__) . '../../keys/rsa_private_key.pem', 'r');`

Comment: @theGreenCabbage one slash is missing, check the first comment, I modified it almost instantly. `fopen(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../keys', 'r')`

Comment: Thank you!! You da real MVP. I used `/../../../` since it was three parents up. Please write your answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you should do is move your private key OUTSIDE of the web server's document root. The nature of the term "private key" tells you that you do NOT want someone to be able to access these keys! Putting them under the web server's docroot exposes them unnecessarily - even if you put rules in place to protect them (e.g., htaccess file), there's simply no reason to put them in a location that is - by definition - intended to be accessible by default.

Depending on what distribution you're going to eventually deploy on, there will likely be a standard location for deploying such; if not, I encourage you to define your own policy, such as putting them under `/etc/opencart/keys`.

Once you know/define your policy, you will have an absolute path that you can use, solving the original problem.